# Is there an R function that can evaluate like values in a column for another column type?

Tags: r, dataframe, sorting, dplyr

Okay, my question wasn’t worded well but I’m struggling to describe it!

I’ve attempted it with the code below but I’m pretty new to R and I’ve kind of hit a road block. I’m open to just hints or suggestions for fxns!

Trying to group by the same plot_ID (without explicitly putting in each individual plot ID since there are many many more) and then counting the amount of each size class for each plot.

```
trees_data$BigTree <- nrow(trees_data[trees_data$dbh_cm > 31.5, 'plot_id' == 'plot_id',])
trees_data$smalltree <- nrow(trees_data[trees_data$plot_id == trees_data$plot_id & trees_data$dbh_cm < 31.5,])

trees_data %>%
   group_by(plot_id) %>%
   summarise(across(c(species,dbh_cm), nrow[trees_data$dbh_cm > 31.5,]))
```

Ideally below, the table would have a BigTree and smalltree column that would have the number of the size classes repeated for each unique plot ID. So one column that has SH_001 will count all the rows of SH_001 with a dbh greater than 31.5 and then run the same for SH_19 and so on.

example trees_data

```
plot_id species dbh_cm
SH_001N CADE    13
SH_001N CADE    14.4
SH_001N CADE    11.3
SH_001N PILA    12.1
SH_001N PILA    23.8
SH_001N CADE    91.2
SH_001N QUKE    74
SH_001N CADE    116.5
SH_19   CADE    35.7
SH_19   CADE    24.2
SH_19   PIPO    38.6
SH_19   PIPO    44.2
SH_19   CADE    38.9
```

I'll update with the error that occurs when I re run the code; I genuinely think my approach is wrong but I can't figure what to do.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're wanting something like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

trees_data |> summarise(big = sum(dbh_cm > 31.5), small = sum(dbh_cm <= 31.5), .by = plot_id)
```

Output:

```
  plot_id big small
1 SH_001N   3     5
2   SH_19   4     1
```

A few pointers:

1. Mixing base R stuff (e.g. `df[id == 2]`) and dplyr stuff (e.g. `df |> filter(id == 2)` produces strange and unintuitive results. I would steer clear of doing that unless you are a wizard
2. Likewise, using across is quite complicated and finicky

Comment: I would recommend the swirl tutorials when you're learning R. They're free, interactive, and how I learned R! :-)

Comment: That worked perfectly thank you!!! and I've been using swirl, it'd been a great help in getting a lot of the basics down :) I want to put myself through a few other courses I've found for free too, since it's so neat to learn R alongside the data analysis I'm doing.